# Batch scripting with silent admin access to install applications

Tags: batch-file

Im having trouble with a script to silently install 2 files without getting an admin prompt. The first file changes an ini to a program can upgrade. The second installs the new application.

The script will then remove the old icon on the users desktop and replace it with a new link to the new application.

Every time I try to run it I get the dreaded UAC Prompt.

I tried to incorporate the batchgotadmin snippet at the top of my file but I cant seem to get it to work right as I still get a admin prompt and I need it to install the application silently with admin rights to the users machine.

Here is my code I'm working with now:

```
    @echo off

   :: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)

   REM --> Check for permissions
   >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
  REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
  if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (

 goto UACPrompt
 ) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
 echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
 echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
 "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
 exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"


:: Installs refresh 
"\\server\share\program1.exe /VERYSILENT /LOG="c:\REFRESH.TXT" 

:: Installs v8
"\\server\share\program2.exe" /VERYSILENT /LOG="C:\INSTALL.TXT" /NORESTART

:: Removes old applicationshortcut
del /Q "%allusersprofile%\desktop\program.lnk"

:: Adds new  application shortcut
xcopy "c:\programfiles(x86)\program.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop"
```

What am I missing to make this work properly?

Comment: Believe it or not you can't bypass security, else there is no security.

Comment: Why can't you install per user.

Comment: if i try to install per user ( which is what i need to do) I get the admin prompt to install the software which is not what we need. we need a zero touch install. 

When I deploy it as a system in sccm to the device it doesn't get installed correctly so were back to installing the application to the user profile without asking for admin rights

Comment: Remove security on what it wants (folders) or Schedule in task scheduler. You can choose the account. Password is done when setting up the task so not needed to be entered when it runs.

Comment: Hi there, 

Sorry about the delayed response. I have tried to deploy these 2 packages with a batch file, a powershell script and even tried it in vbs but i still cannot get it to work. A scheduled task doesnt seem to want to go through either. 

Would someone beable to help me create a powershell script similar to a batch file i was using so that I can try to get these pieces of software to install? I cant seem to deploy it as an exe package in SCCM either because the software has to be installed from the source application server